# Error STDERR: <file>: is outside repository

Tags: python, git

I have created a file(my_f) and a directory(my_dir) under my local repo using my python script (my script, my_f and my_dir are all under the same path in my repo).

I moved my_f into my_dir inside my script and as the final step I want to add this file to my tracking file list, make a commit and push it to remote repo. When I run sh.git('add', /absolute/path/to/my_dir/my_f) I get this error:

STDERR:
**fatal: /absolute/path/to/my_dir/my_f: 'absolute/path/to/my_dir/my_f' is outside repository**

/absolute/path/to/my_dir/my_f: This is the absolute path to my file and its type is Posixpath.
I have also converted this path to script and tried in in sh.git('add', '/absolute/path/to/my_dir/my_f') but I get the same error.

If I manually add the file to repo in my terminal using git add command I have no problem! Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What working directory are you in, in both cases (the manual command-line usage that works, and the scripted one that doesn't)? Granted, git _may_ support being called without a cwd in the working tree (or an environment variable pointing to that tree), but I wouldn't assume that it does unless you tested it.

Comment: That is to say, _in your terminal_, try `cd /; git add /absolute/path/to/my_dir/my_f`. Or `cd` into a completely different git repository, and try the same thing. If it only works when you `cd`'d into a directory in the same working tree as your target file (or if it _doesn't_ work after you `cd` into a different git repo's working tree), there's your problem.

Comment: I agree. Within your python script, you should cd to be inside the repo, and then add the file with a relative path from where your cd'd to.